# How should I use @types with TypeScript 2

Tags: typescript, tsd, typescript-typings

So far we are used to **tsd** or (The better version of it) **typings**

But now that TypeScript 2 offers the new `@types` feature, how should I convert my current project to work with @types?

I have tsd.json (typings.json is some cases) with all the dependencies, what are the steps to do the move to TypeScript 2?

What are the *new* best practices?
Does @types support specific versions?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's very simple. Just install the definitions that you need via npm.

For example if you need lodash you can do:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Once it's installed you can use it right away in your project. Typescript will resolve the typings for the installed @types package from the *node_modules/@types* folder by default. There's no need for a *tsd.json* or *typings.json* file anymore.

Additional points:

- The major and minor version of the @types package in npm should correspond with the package version.
- You can search for types here: http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/
- Read about [`typeRoots` and `types` here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). Specifically pay attention to these two points:

  - If `typeRoots` is specified in *tsconfig.json*, then only specified folders will be used for the type roots. That will exclude *./npm_modules/@types/* unless you specify it.
  - If `types` is  specified in *tsconfig.json*, then only the packages specified will be included.

Read more in the blog post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Comment: What about the `dt~***` syntax ?

Comment: @Royi I've never seen that syntax for @types—only for [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/tsd.md). I thought definitions on definitely typed were [published automatically to @types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#faq). Do you have more information on that?

Comment: Already found it . [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734991/whats-the-difference-from-installing-type-definition-files-using-typings-vs-npm).

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that the syntax has changes since 2. (IIUC)

Comment: Thank you - spent so much time screwing around with "typings".

Comment: This answer, specifically not setting `typeRoots` and `types`, helped me with typescript 3.9.x in 2020.

Answer (score 40):

**Typescript 2.0** gets rid of previous **Typings** system.
Now **Typescript 2.0**  should by default look into `./node_modules/@types` and get types that you installed as the separate node modules, e.g. `npm install --save @types/react` (as mentioned by @David Sherret)

There is a bug in the current version **Typescript 2.0 beta**, which does not load new types. Manually via cmd new tsc compiles files, but there is no IntelliSense support in VS 2015, and no errors are showed while a .ts file is in edit mode.

To resolve it modify `tsconfig.json` with the similar settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     // ... other config rows 
   "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/" ],
    "types": [ "jquery", "react", "react-dom", /*... your other types */ ],
  }
}
```

For me manual `"types"` declaration helped resolved this issue, for other guys `"typeRoots"` helped. Hopefully it will save developer's hours.

Comment: "typeRoots" worked for me, thank you! Root problem was that my tsconfig.json file is in my projects subfolder. So I added: `"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types/" ]`

Comment: The above issue is fixed and now typescript loads the new types directly from `./node_modules/@types`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they are all just npm packages, you can find all the supported ones [here](https://www.npmjs.com/~types).

**tsc** will pick up any types in the **node_modules** folder.

You can move the dependencies you have in **typings.json** in **package.json** (provided you change the names too ofcourse).

You can read more about that [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Answer (score 2):

> how should I convert my current project to work with @types

I definitely recommend holding on for a bit longer.

e.g. issues are still getting fixed ... just 4 hours ago : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9725#issuecomment-233469422