# TypeScript 2 and Sublime: Automatic reference to node_modules/@types?

Tags: sublimetext3, typescript2.0

I've updated my project to TypeScript 2 and it's all good. I'm using the new way to use typings, now stored in `node_modules/@types`.

The problem is that installing new typings doesn't automatically work with Sublime. I have to manually add the references to have them recognized inside the editor.

Is there a convenient solution to my problem?

Edit:
Duplicate of: [How should I use @types with TypeScript 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444279/how-should-i-use-types-with-typescript-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I use @types with TypeScript 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444279/how-should-i-use-types-with-typescript-2)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `tsconfig.json` try adding `typeRoots` & `types` for the location of the typings and what types should be referenced. Like this:

`"typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]`

```
"types": [
  "jasmine",
]
```

`
See if that works.

Comment: For some reason, my Sublime is not able to find the types this way :(

Comment: Well you are on Typescript version 2.0
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Is the path to your node_modules correct? 

If it is in `src/client/app` then you would need `'.../.../node_modules/@types'` or if your `tsconfig.json` is on the root then it would be `'./node_modules/@types'`

Comment: Could you try and include the missing type *package name* inside your 

`types : []`

It is a list of names of type definitions to include. 

Was this what you meant by manually entering the references?