# Integrate FlowJs with angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, flow-js

I know there is no direct integration of FlowJs with angular2 so i am trying to implement it by following ways but didn't get any success:

**By Declare direct:**

Included flow.js script file in index.html and following is the code of component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Flow: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-page',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public message: string;

    constructor() {
        this.message = 'Dashboard';
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        var flow = new Flow({
            target: '/api/photo/redeem-upload-token',
            query: { upload_token: 'my_token' }
        });
    }
}
```

In this its giving me error: ' Flow is not defined'

**By using @typings:**

I have installed the @typings by @types/flowjs and then installed flow.js by using "npm install --save-dev @flowjs/flow.js"  and then i have written following code in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Flow from "@types/flowjs"; 
//or
```

//import * as Flow from "flowjs"; 
    @Component({
        selector: 'dashboard-page',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
    })

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public message: string;

    constructor() {
        this.message = 'Dashboard';
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        var flow = new Flow({
            target: '/api/photo/redeem-upload-token',
            query: { upload_token: 'my_token' }
        });
    }

}
```

But in this its giving an error: "/node_modules/@types/flowjs/index.d.ts' is not a module".

How can i implement FlowJs with angular2?

Comment: Perhaps try `import * as flow from '@flow/dist/flow'` ?

Comment: @JoeKeene- my folder structure is "node_modules\@flowjs\flow.js\dist" and in dist folder there is flow.js (javascript) file exist not ts file and i tried "import * as flow from '@flowjs/flow.js/dist/flow'" but its showing cannot find module.                                                                                                                            And In my "@types" i have this structure "\node_modules\@types\flowjs" and in the flowjs folder i have index.d.ts,packages.json,types-metadata.json files exist. And i have also added the index.d.ts data in quesition.

Comment: Ah ok - have you looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379116/using-flow-js-in-angular-2-typescript ?