# Using flow.js in Angular 2 Typescript (Cont)

Tags: angular, flow-js

This question is related to this question: [Using flow.js in Angular 2 Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379116/using-flow-js-in-angular-2-typescript).

Has anybody had any success in implementing `flow.js`? One of the comments says to follow 'angular-cli way' and I have but still cant get it to work.

Can someone put detail explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it into index.html and use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/flowjs) typescript declaration.