# Install Node module in TypeScript using Typings and NPM

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to import a Node module in the most correct way possible.  I would like the line:

`import * as pg from "pg"`

to work.  But right now it raises a:

`Cannot find module 'pg' error`.

I'm hoping I am missing something simple.

---

My failing strategy:

1. `npm install pg --save`
2. `typings install pg --save`
3. `"files": [
     "./typings/index.d.ts",` in tsconfig.json.

Let me know if you have any advice for my approach.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I raises this error on compilation or in runtime?

Comment: if you are using TypeScript 2, this might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38444504/5115768

Comment: And you are sure that step 2 went well? Often the command is `typings install dt~pg --global`.  Other than that it looks like you are on the right track to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
npm install @types/pg
```

Then go ahead and import it

```
import * as pg from "pg"
```