# Aurelia typescript skeleton errors

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, aurelia

I have got the aurelia skeleton downloaded and when using gulp watch all is ok.

Unfortunately, when I try to run in from visual studio i get a number of errors:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/child-router.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/demo.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/skeleton.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/welcome.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/app.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/child-router.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/setup.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/users.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/demo.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/skeleton.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/welcome.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/app.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/setup.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files. skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS6059  File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/users.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton (tsconfig project)     1   Active
>   Error   TS2375  Duplicate number index signature.   skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts    75  Active
>   Error   TS2374  Duplicate string index signature.   skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts    130 Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   20  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   20  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   20  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   20  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   20  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   30  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   30  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   30  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   30  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   39  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   39  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   39  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   39  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   50  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   50  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   50  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Headers'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   71  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   76  Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Request'. skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   261 Active
>   Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Response'.    skeleton (tsconfig project) C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\typings\modules\aurelia-fetch-client\index.d.ts   261 Active
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/demo.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/skeleton.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/e2e/src/welcome.po.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.   skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/app.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.    skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/child-router.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.   skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/setup.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.   skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1
>   Error   TS6059  Build:File 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/test/unit/users.spec.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:/Users/sbloom/testing/PVPortal/src/skeleton/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.  skeleton    C:\Users\sbloom\testing\PVPortal\src\skeleton\tsc   1

Can someone please help and point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Which of the TypeScript skeletons are you using? webpack or JSPM?

Comment: skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore, thanks

Comment: @StuartBloom Did you found the solution? Because I have the same issue right now.

Comment: @J4N sorry, but no i didn't.  I moved to an application created with the Aurelia cli, and it seems to be working fine.  Sorry I cannot help you, best of luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered this question here: [How to create aurelia typescript project with vs2017rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138343/how-to-create-aurelia-typescript-project-with-vs2017rc/)

The answer uses the Aurelia skeleton-navigation 1.1.2 skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore project as base with Visual Studio 2017 and resolves the same errors you describe here. I have tested this with the VS pro and community edition. I've also resolved these same errors for Visual studio 2015 and this should still apply even if you are using VS 2015.

There are some other things that might go wrong, but if you start from scratch with the skeleton-navigation 1.1.2 this should work.