# Stop the TypeScript definition wack-a-mole between Aurelia CLI and Visual Studio 2017 builds

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, aurelia

I have an Aurelia project in a NET Core project. I am able to build the project using Aurelia CLI but the Visual Studio build fails with the following TypeScript errors:

```
Build:Cannot find name 'RequestInit'. 
Build:Cannot find name 'Request'. 
Build:Cannot find name 'Response'.
```

[image: Visual Studio errors]

Most of these errors are coming from the `aurelia-fetch-client`. 
Next I try to fix the problem by installing the package `@types/whatwg-fetch`. The Visual Studio errors disappear, but now the Aurelia CLI will not build. The errors thrown are:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.
Duplicate identifier 'HeadersInit'.
Duplicate identifier 'Headers'.
Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
Duplicate identifier 'Request'.
Duplicate identifier 'Response'.
... and many more duplicate identifiers.
```

The collisions are in whatwg-fetch and lib.dom.d.ts. How to I get both builds back to green?

*Update*
I see Request definition in `lib.dom.d.ts` so I feel that Aurelia CLI is working and Visual Studio is broken. Why would Visual Studio not pick up these typings when I have the following tsconfig:

```
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "aurelia_project"
],
"filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

*Update 2* If I add the lib.dom.d.ts file to the files array in the tsconfig, the errors disappear in Visual Studio.

```
"files": [
    "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.string.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts"
]
```

There must be a better way.

Comment: Just turn off VS typescript compilation ;)

Comment: @mgiesa It feels dirty, but it worked. I build with Aurelia CLI so theres no point to having VS build my TS. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, provided by @mgiesa, was to disable Visual Studio TypeScript compilation. The various build tools were all competing and had varying TypeScript configurations. This has become much easier with the Visual Studio releases since the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot of the same errors I've managed to solve earlier on Stack Overflow, please take a look here and see if this could be of any use to you: [How to create aurelia typescript project with vs2017rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138343/how-to-create-aurelia-typescript-project-with-vs2017rc/42736852#42736852)

Perhaps you have solved most of the issues in the link already or maybe this does not apply to your specific situation with Aurelia CLI, but-- This command: `npm install typescript@2.1.5 --save` has helped me and a couple of others with similar errors coming from `URL` and `Fetch` in particular.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not fix the problem.