# convert JSON interface to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript

I have an interface class and JSON file which I would like to convert to a list and work on it. for instance , getting `Racename` from every object in the JSON into a list\array.
is it possible?
that's the interface:

```
interface IRunners{
Racename: string;
Category:number; 
Gender:string; 
Work:string; 
FullName:string; 
Rank:number;
Point:number;
Numparticipant:number;
rankparticipant:number;
precentagePart:string; 
NumRaces:number; 
RaceTime:string; 
rankCat:number; 
PointCat:number; 
RaceDate:string;
}
```

This is the JSON file (`Runners.json`):

```
[
  {"Racename":"A1","Category":34,"Gender":"זכר","Work":"AMDOCS","FullName":"Simon Work ","Rank":1,"Ponit":1,"Numparticipant":0,"rankparticipant":0,"precentagePart":"0","NumRaces":1,"RaceTime":"2018-10-18T00:34:20","rankCat":1,"PointCat":1,"RaceDate":"2018-10-05"}
]
```

I'm subscribing it as follow:

```
  this.runnerService.getRunners().subscribe(
        runners=>{
          this.runners = runners;
          this.filteredCompetitions = this.runners;
          this.filteredRunners = this.runners;
        }
```

I would like to convert the `runners` JSON into an array in order to make some changes and get some data out of it.
I'm a newbie to Typescript and Angular so probably I'm making some mistakes.

Comment: Post sample output (Array), what exactly you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript JSON string to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171620/typescript-json-string-to-class)

Comment: @Sachink updated my question with an example at the beginning of my post

Comment: Do you want to iterate over IRunners members? It seems that the runners json is already a list (Runners.json). So, can you be more clear of what you want?

Comment: @ArthurSilva exactly..

Comment: So you can use this approach to iterate over properties: [typescript-iterate-interface-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670705/typescript-iterate-interface-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
// Assumes runners.json is a file in the same directory as this file
const jsonArray = require("./runners.json")

// // returns ["A1"]
const listOfRacenames = jsonArray.map(d => d.Racename)
```

Comment: means I need to change my interface to your suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to generate TypeScript interfaces from the JSON file? It's not clear where you're starting and where you'd like to end up.

Comment: as a newbie, I'm nut sure what I'm trying to do, but I would like to end up iterating the JSON and get some data from every object in it

Comment: In that case, my answer above will do what you need it to do. There's also [Array#forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you'd like to perform some arbitrary operation on each of your JSON objects — i.e., you don't want to return a result. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: it makes sense, the only problem currently is my JSON is in different file(`runners.json`) and I'm not sure I can implement it exactly as you suggested. am I wrong? 10x btw...

Comment: Try ```require('path/to/your/json/file.json')```.

Comment: Updated answer above to use an external JSON file.