# Using jQuery with Typescript 2

Tags: jquery, typescript2.0

I'm new to Typscript 2. What i'm trying to do is to use jQuery within typescript. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript/32052431#32052431) question  i read that you need two things:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

This installs package '@types/jquery 2.0.39'.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.39",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
```

Then, in the Typescript file i put this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

but i got typescript error 'Cannot find module 'jquery'. What am I doing wrong?

Same error with

```
import $ = require("jquery");
```

Full typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div id="test"></div>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor() {
        $('#test').html('This is a test');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you done `npm install jquery --save` along with this?

Comment: Yes, i have. Now I have errors in index.d.ts file, for instance:

Line: attr(attributeName: string, value: string|number|null): JQuery;
Error1: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
Error2: Type expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only install jquery's typings. You will need jQuery itself, too:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Furthermore, since you use typescript@2, you don't need the `typings` package anymore. This will now be handled via npm and the `@types` packages, available at `$types/{your-package}`, in your case `@types/jquery`:

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed Visual Studio update (Tools -> Extensions and Updates) "Typescript 2.0.6 for Visual Studio 2015".

Also, I installed the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler
- Microsoft.Typescript.MSBuild

Then I installed jQuery and jQuery typings via npm:

```
npm install jquery @types/jquery --save
```

And finally, in `tsconfig.json:`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ... other compiler options ...
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/" ],
    "types": ["jquery" ]
  },
```

Now I can build the project and `$` is recognized as jQuery inside the TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks so much, the `typeRoots` property saved me. I did not have NPM or a `node_modules` folder, I just wanted to get proper types by installing `@types/jquery` using libman. But without the whole NPM thing `tsc` seems to not know where his types are, even when you add them to your include list.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is a basic `npm` install for `jQuery` first in your project directory.

`npm install jquery`

And then use it via:

`import $ = require('jquery');`

Always works.

Comment: Does this take typescript and its typing into account?

Comment: Does work in Typescript projects, ignores typings initially. If you want typings, you can install via provided repo.

Comment: I did this, but the module is still not available (cannot find module jquery)

Comment: This was the key for me. I was trying to do `import $ from "jquery";` but `import $ = require('jquery');` worked.

Comment: To add to the above, I was using "module": "commonjs" in tsconfig.js. If using "module": "es6" then you'd want to use `import $ from "jquery";`

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have errors in index.d.ts file, for instance: Line:
>   attr(attributeName: string, value: string|number|null): JQuery;
>   Error1: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or
>   constructor implementation. Error2: Type expected

Not an answer to your original question but to the follow-up, as i am not allowed to answer on your comment:
I had the same error, as a workaround i removed the offending line from the index.d.ts of jQuery and was able to use jQuery whithin typescript. I do not know yet if this has any unwanted side-effects though, so use this at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'll give it a shot, since i ran out of options