# How to import JQuery into a Typescript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, import

### Update

No import was required.  Instead, I needed to add a reference to the top of the file.  So the first line of my WebAPI.js should have been `/// <reference path ="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>` instead of `import { $ } from '../jquery-3.1.1';`

---

I am trying to import jQuery to use in a Typescript file, but I am receiving a variety of errors with everything I try.  I followed the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763684/how-to-require-jquery-via-amd-in-typescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826503/using-jquery-with-typescript-2?noredirect=1&lq=1), but without any luck.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "out": "Scripts/CCSEQ.Library.js",
    "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
}
```

### WebAPI.js

```
import { $ } from '../jquery-3.1.1';

export class ExpenseTransaction extends APIBase {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    Get(): void {
        let expenses: Array<Model.ExpenseTransaction>;
        let self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.Connection,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data: any): void {
                expenses = self.ConvertToEntity(data.value);
            },
            error: function (data: any): void { console.log(data.status); }
        });
    };
}
```

I have also tried `import * as $ from '../jquery.3.1.1'`

### Errors

- `Module jquery-3.1.1 has no exported member $`
- `Property ajax does not exist on type (selector: any, context: any) => any`

Comment: Did you install the typings? `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
`

Comment: @Rens I have the `typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts` file from NuGet.  Is that the same thing?

Comment: Did you install this package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Comment: @Rens Yes I did

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An import is not required. Instead, add a reference to the Typescript definition file the top of the file. So the first line of the `WebAPI.js` should be

```
/// <reference path ="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

instead of

```
import { $ } from '../jquery-3.1.1';
```

According to the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/wiki) wiki:

> A TypeScript declaration file is way of defining the types, functions
>   and parameters in an external third-party JavaScript library. By using
>   a declaration file in your TypeScript code will enable Intellisense
>   and type checking against the external library you are using.

`jquery.d.ts` is a part of the [DefinitelyTyped Library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) found on GitHub.  Definitely Typed can be include in Visual Studio projects via the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 41):

You have to import it as `import * as $ from "jquery";`, according to typescript's [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), and [jquery's definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts) the module is defined as an ambient module:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
```

According to [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html):

> Ambient declarations is a promise that you are making with the compiler.
>   If these do not exist at runtime and you try to use them, things will break without warning.

Comment: Easiest would be just `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';` and then use `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere.

Answer (score 22):

**do this :** after installing jquery with npm or used with cdn

**first:**

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

**and after:**

> import * as $ from 'jquery';

Answer (score 5):

## es5

Importing is as simple as:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

But only if we install related `.d.ts` files:

```sh
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

### es6

Same as above, but if you want to be able to use "`$`" as function, to listen for document-ready event (like "`$(function () { ... })`"), then continue reading.

First, in `tsconfig.json` file, do something like:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Then import without "`* as` " part, like:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

See also [stackoverflow.com/Understanding-esModuleInterop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)

Answer (score 3):

Tim's solution using the reference compiler directive works, however there is an easier way now.

In tsconfig.json, if you set typeRoots, you don't need to do anything at all in your .ts files. TypeScript does the work for you.

**How does it work?**

In my solution, I pull in all my @types via npm, so those are placed at ./node_modules/@types. I also have a few types I created by hand at ./@types.

In my tsconfig.json, I added:

```
 "compilerOptions": {     
   // lots of other config here
   "typeRoots": [
     "./node_modules/@types",
     "./@types"
   ]
  }
```

Now all my types are discovered and used by the compiler automatically, so there's no need to bother with reference tags!

**In conclusion...**

I should note that if you do this and you try to explicitly import jquery, it will fail, and you will be confused. I sure was.

Comment: My tsconfi doesn't have typeRoots defined. which still references @types. Because of this I am having issue. It doesn't compain at compile time but at runtime it gives error. So even if I dont include import it is not complaining.

Comment: Maybe define it? Check out the docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html  under "@types, typeRoots and types". It describes how, by default, it tries to find all visible @types, and it seems this behavior is not working for you in prod.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your import with 
declare let $ : any;

Comment: The problem with doing this is that you lose all Intellisense and type-checking against the JQuery namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio community, to do the work I have to add jquery in html at head / script section, then add my app.ts just under jquery script section then I add the reference to jquery lib in my typescript source.

In html page, head section :

```
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

In app.ts, first line of ts script  :

```
/// <reference path ="./Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```