# TypeScript Typings - .Net Core 1.0

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have created a .Net Core 1.0 MVC project.  I am using TypeScript files.
I want to transmit some data using the jquery call $.ajax but the compiler does not recognised the dollar sign.
I have tried various permutations of...

import * as $ from "../lib/jquery/dist/jquery";

...but to no avail. TypeScript files that do not call jquery functions work perfectly.  When I put the $.ajax call on the view using javascript it works fine.  However, I want to use TypeScript for obvious reasons.
Could someone suggest the correct reference please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import JQuery into a Typescript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783307/how-to-import-jquery-into-a-typescript-file)

Comment: Possible isn’t good enough if you don’t provide a link!

Comment: Apologies - I could not see the link on my phone screen.  Sorry again.

Comment: Vijayanath pointed me in the right direction.  I downloaded a copy of jquery.d.ts from here...

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts

and manually loaded it into my lib folder and then placed this line at the top of the TypeScript file...

/// <reference path="../lib/jquery.d.ts" />

Now this symbol $.ajax compiles.

Comment: good to know your problem solved. Please up flag my comment if it helped. Thank you