# How to use a JQuery element in Vue 'data' option using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I wish to hold onto a reference of a jQuery element in the vue 'data' object but TypeScript is complaining at me that the type does not match.

How can I fix this?

**[EDIT]**
Think I largely fixed this by fooling TS by referencing a non-existing jQuery element as a default value to the property.  After that I can reference the prop and it believes it is a jQuery element... - it still feels a little 'hacky' though...

Any help much approciated!

```
var x = Vue.extend({
data: function () {
    return {
      _componenentDidMount: false,
      _myJQueryElement: undefined,
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    // remember we are now mounted
    this._componenentDidMount = true;                       // this is OK

    // on mounting I wish to set the '_myJQueryElement' 
    this._myJQueryElement = $('.z-vertical-scrollbar');     // this FAILS
},
methods: {
    B() {

        // I can do this...  (typescript cleverly infers the type to be 'boolean')
        var didMount = this._componenentDidMount;           // this is OK

        // Now I wish to do 'jquery' stuff with the element
        var top = this._myJQueryElement.offset().top;       // this FAILS

    }
}
```

}

(below is what the code looks like on the screen)

[image]

[EDIT 2]
(the '**fixed**' version - making TypeScript believe it is a jQuery element by referencing a non existing element)...

[image]

[EDIT 3]
(yet another differently '**fixed**' version - using TypeScript to define the properties properly).. - even though I am using 'any' as a get-out clause since jQuery returns a *JQuery | undefined* back which is tricky to handle...

[image]

Comment: I  think this could be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783307/how-to-import-jquery-into-a-typescript-file

Comment: Thanks, but I have jQuery already globally imported and it works well - my question is purely on how to get rid of the red 'squiggly lines in the above image

Comment: I know the problem must lie with the fact that TS can infer the type of the _componentDidMount property but can't set the _myJQueryElement property unless I give is some sort of default? - which I have also tried and kind of halves the issue... (see edited picture above)

Answer (score 0):

The correct type should be:

```
_myJqueryElement: JQuery<HTMLElement>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that does not work either (I tried that already). As I am trying to elude to, the TS compiler infers the type from the 'data' return object, so what do I need to specify my _myJQueryElement property to be (if anything) - basically, how do I get rid of the red 'scribbly lines'!

Comment: Can you provide some repo with you problem? I tried to reproduce here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zpgtbw and it works

Comment: It requires Vue - do you use Vue?  The problem is within the way the 'data' object is setup.  If it wasn't for TypeScript none of this would be an issue :(

Comment: I tried your exact same code, here in a vue mockup and it works also