# How do I write tests using jQuery in ts-jest when using ES imports?

Tags: jquery, jsdom, ts-jest

I'm trying to write unit tests using TypeScript, Jest and jQuery. I got pretty far but when I run the tests, I get "jQuery requires a window with a document"

Apparently, the problem is that `import * as $ from "jquery"` ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783307/how-to-import-jquery-into-a-typescript-file)) will also initialize jQuery but at that time, there is no window. What I would need is a "lazy" version of the jQuery module, kind of what `$(document).ready(...)` would usually but for the `$` symbol itself.

Background: I have jQuery installed as `npm install @types/jquery`. I'm using `jsdom` to create a fake window. I'm using `ts-jest` to transpile the TS files into JavaScript for `jest`. Tests are run with `npx jest --watch` or `npm t`.

I would like to avoid using `global.$` in a [Jest setupFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) because many tests don't need the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but you can't use $ in the code under test, so it only works for code which you wrote / can change.

Instead of using `$` directly, wrap it in a provider:

```
export class JQueryProvider {
    constructor(public jq: any) {
        // empty
    }

    get(selector: string): JQuery {
        return this.jq(selector)
    }
}
```

This way, we can hide the details of where `$` comes from. Also the `get()` method will cast the result to the correct type, even though the input `jq` is of type `any`.

This code should go into a shared utility module.

Tests should include a module with this setup code:

```
import { JQueryProvider } from "./utils"
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";

export type WithJQueryFunction = (jq: JQueryProvider) => void;

export function withJQuery(fn: WithJQueryFunction): void {
    // Create window before loading jquery
    const window = new JSDOM().window 

    // Create jQuery instance
    const $ = require('jquery')(window);

    // Create provider to avoid the global variable $
    const jq = new JQueryProvider($)

    fn(jq)
}
```

Note that I'm using `require()` instead of `import` since I'm not sure how to achieve the same effect.

Tests will now look like this:

```
withJQuery((jq) => {
    describe('jQuery tests', () => {
        it('empty div', () => {
            const parent = jq.get('<div>')
            expect(parent[0]).toMatchSnapshot()
        })      

        it('empty div with class', () => {
            const parent = jq.get('<div>').addClass('foo')
            expect(parent[0]).toMatchSnapshot()
        })      
    })
})
```

Example for production code:

```
export class DivAppender implements Appender {
    constructor(public jq: JQueryProvider, public parent: JQuery, public dateFormat = TIME_FORMAT) {
        // empty
    }

    append(event: LogEvent): void {
        const element = this.jq.get('<div>').addClass('event')
        ...

const appender = new DivAppender(new JQueryProvider($), $('body'))
```