# calling jquery $(html:string) from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, typescript

I am using *TypeScript* to generate some *DOM* element from a templated `string`. Now I know that in plain old *javascript* + *JQuery* you can do: `var domObj = $(myString)` or to make it more evident: `var comObj = $('<div></div>');` and it works just like that.

I've been trying to do the same with TS and I always get some error telling me it can't say which overload to use.

Is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do?
Can it be done in TS?

### Edit:

The issue I'm facing is not how to use `JQuery` from TypeScript is about a specific feature I want to load a `string` variable to a `JQuery` object, I know it can be done in plain old `js` but I get overloading errors when doing so.

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript) which asks how to use `JQuery` from `ts`, which I have mostly figured out except for that little details I have just mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript)

Comment: @JJJ I already have `jquery.d.ts` and everything else works fine, it loading the `string` as a `JQuery` that's causing me trouble.

Comment: @JoshCrozier yes it does, thank you very much. if you could please add that as an answer and elaborate/explain it a little more I'd more than happy to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above, you need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in order to avoid that error.

The most versatile option would be to use the `any` type since that will prevent typing errors from being thrown:

```
var comObj = ($('<div></div>') as any);

// or

var comObj = (<any>$('<div></div>'));

// or

var comObj: any = $('<div></div>');
```

Without seeing the full code, it's hard to know what exactly was happening in your case.

However, without context, it seems like the problem is that the compiler thinks that you are passing a string that represents a CSS selector, but in reality you were passing in stringified HTML, which results in the error that you are seeing.

---

As a side note, here is a relevant snippet in the TypeScript documentation under [advanced intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). As you can see, the variable `result` is essentially coerced using the `<any>` type assertion:

```
let result = <T & U>{};
for (let id in first) {
    (<any>result)[id] = (<any>first)[id];
}
```