# jQuery methods autocomplete in a TypeScript file in WebStorm / PhpStorm

Tags: jquery, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

Can anyone tell me please how to autocomplete jQuery methods in a TypeScript file in WebStorm / PhpStorm IDE?

I just need to autocomplete, not import jQuery. Because if I import like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

in my `.ts` file, then it includes

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

in my generated `.js` file.

Comment: Have a look here for some hints, for example: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206891089-Use-typings-TypeScript-definitions .. or this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32050645/783119

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now my IDE autocompletes jQuery in .ts file automatically. I don't need to import any jquery reference. I don't know what happened first time. But now it's working automatically.

Thank you all.