# How to translate simple Ajax to TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I have a simple JavaScript code which using Ajax. I want translate this ajax query to TypeScript for more object oriented view. With class and method and hard data types (similar to Java:-).

Help me translate if it posible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-viewscope').click(function() {
        $ajax({
            url: 'get_data_servlet',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: For simple uses like this it's better this way.

Comment: Why don't you just setup an interface that type checks the response? and handle it that way.

Comment: Related : [How to use jQuery with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript)

Comment: @Anamul Hasan for simple yes. But this example for understand principle my real code different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, but slightly dated article explains the basics of how to wrap your API calls in a TypeScript class.  Pay attention to the Customer class, which contains four functions - SelectAll(), Insert(), Update() and Delete() that call the respective Web API methods using jQuery, all while maintaining type-checking (alas, I was once a Java developer who ran into the same concerns when learning dynamically typed Javascript):

- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-typescript-to-perform-crud-operations.htm