# Using jQuery with the ASP.NET Core 2 React template

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, module

I am trying to build a web app based on the new **React template in ASP.NET Core 2.0**

I want to make an ajax request via jQuery. My issue is that the template by default uses TypeScript (tsx) files and if I try to do something along the lines of

```
import { $ } from 'jquery'
```

I get a TypeScript error, that says it cannot determine type for $.

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052431/8991878, I went ahead and  did an `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`.

The first error went away, but now I get

> Module "jquery: has no exported member $.

Another post I found suggested **removing the curly brackets {}**. After doing that 
I instead got

> Module "jquery" has no default export

I am a back-end developer and I do not have lots of experience with both TypeScript and jQuery so I guess I am just doing something dumb incorrectly.

I read about TypeScript's module resolution here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html and I did verify that my package.json file has `"@types/jquery": "^3.2.16"`. I also have jquery in both `node_modules` and `node_modules/@types`

Comment: Import is wrong. It should be: `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: Not sure if you read to the end of my post. I did try that and I got a different error :)

Comment: Hmm right. Which `jquery` version are you using?

Comment: "jquery": "3.2.1" and "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16"
These are both from the package.json file

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct style of import for jQuery is the simplest form:

```
import 'jquery';
```

If you are doing this with the native browser loader, it would need a file extension at the moment, so the plain browser version would be:

```
import './jquery.js';
```

(This is with the actual jQuery file being copied to root, so the browser doesn't have to navigate into node_modules.

Comment: This did resolve the issue. However, now when I try to call $.ajax I get $ is not defined. Any idea about how can I get this fixed?

Comment: UPDATE: Well, not sure if it is the best solution, but I did an import * as $ from 'jquery' and it managed to work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, solved it by changing `import { $ } from 'jquery'` to `import * as $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: jQuery does support CommonJS module syntax, but in a browser it sets: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;` - which is why I wouldn't use an alias when importing jQuery (specifically jQuery... in case anyone reads this and thinks I am talking generally!)

Comment: In the future, they will almost certainly gravitate towards ECMAScript modules in the jQuery library. That will change the answer when it happens.