# Add custom.js scripts to Angular 5 (MEAN) index.html file

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I had a static website and I'm trying to kinda convert it into MEAN stack using Angular 5.

I want to add some scripts and styles for galleries, scrolling etc. to my HTML. The scripts need jQuery and I don't have to access them really they just need to run. I added them in the .angular-cli.json like so:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/normalize.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/owl.carousel.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/owl.theme.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/main.css",
    "./src/app/assets/css/responsive"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js",
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/imagesloaded.js",
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js",
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js",
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
    "./src/app/assets/plugins/main.js"
  ],
```

Also added *allowJs: true* in the *tsconfig.app.json*

But I get an error when I try to run **ng serve** or **ng build**.

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>   TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at hasOwnProperty ()
>       at Object.hasProperty (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2229:31)
>       at parseConfig (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:71815:16)
>       at /home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:71721:22
>       at Object.parseJsonConfigFileContent (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:71735:11)
>       at Object.readTsconfig (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/read-tsconfig.js:8:32)
>       at new NgCliWebpackConfig (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:19:42)
>       at Class.run (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:71:29)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/home/robin/webdevelopment/Guenters-Fahrschulen/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)

My linter also throws an error on `$(document).ready();` but how would I replace it?

Comment: It's a long story, you may try to start from [How to use jQuery with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript)

Comment: Now I get this: An error occured during the build:
Error: ENOENT: .../src/app/assets/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', but the path is correct