# Use jQuery in TypeScript in VS Code

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add jQuery to a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code. The goal is to use it via the $, as I would do in plain JavaScript, WITHOUT providing the jQuery  tag in the head of my html.

I have my jquery and its definition installed on the project:

[image: Packages]

Hence, $ and intellisense is working like a charm:

[image: VSCode]

But opening the page I'm getting the error: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

I have read several related topics, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript), but the question there is about Visual Studio, and the last answer also suggest to load jQuery via  tag in html, what I'm trying to avoid.

So how do I tell the ts compiler to include jQuery? I cannot import it because there is no export in jQuery. Am I missing something from tsconfig.json?

[image: tsconfig]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your packages are installed in the node_modules folder. You need to somehow serve these up on the page. As it stands only your own javascript code is included (the `/// <reference path='...'` style reference is a design-time only thing) on the page.

You also need to include the jquery library in order to avoid the run-time error.

You have a couple of options:

1. Simply reference the jquery script in your html (something you said you wanted to avoid)
2. Use a build tool such as webpack or browserify/tsify to import your references and change the `/// <reference path='...'` reference to `import * as $ from "jquery";` in which case the bundler will add the imported script to your outputed js file

More information here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html

As an aside, this isn't really a typescript thing - if using plain js you would still either need to use the build tool with an import statement or have the jquery library loaded onto your page.