# Is there any equivalent for $(".class").click(); in Typescript?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am using date range picker in angular.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger daterange-ranges">
<i class="icon-calendar22 position-left"></i> <span></span> 
<b class="caret"></b>
</button>
```

When I click this, I get the dropdown to select the date-range with an Apply Button which has a class "applyBtn".

In JQuery there is an option  `$(".class").click();` to get `onclick` function. 
I can't write `(click)="getdateRange()"`. Is there any equivalent for `$(".class").click();` in typescript?

I want something like,

`$(".applyBtn").click(function(){ alert("The button was clicked."); });`

Comment: If you have jQuery definitions the same should work

Comment: If using angular then you can use Renderer2.listen. Reference https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen

Comment: Hi Hemchandra, TypeScript doesn't supply any particular framework of its own. You can continue to use jQuery in your TypeScript application if you would like to (or any other framework). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript

Answer (score 2):

you can use pure javascript and do this

```
    document.querySelector('.applyBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
       alert("The button was clicked.");
    });
```

it will do the same thing as `$(".applyBtn").click();` in JQuery

Comment: But what you wrote is not a function. I want something like,

`$(".applyBtn").click(function(){
    alert("The button was clicked.");
});`

Comment: what's wrong here why you can't do it like so
 `document.querySelector('.applyBtn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      alert("The button was clicked.");
  });`

Comment: you can add this in your ngOnInit or in another lifecycle hook

Answer (score 1):

As I see in tags you are using an Angular. Using jQuery isn't a good idea in Angular since it has its own great tools.

To make a click handler you need to do following

```
<anyTag (click)="clickHandler($event)"></anyTag>
```

Then in your component paste next:

```
public clickHandler(event) {
  //do whatever you want
}
```

If you want to know what's passed with `$event` you are welcome to angular.io API

P.S. If you want to re-use it you need to make it an extra component like `date-picker.component.ts` and paste it there. Then you could access form's value by passing it into created component via `[date]="date"` and retrieve it in component `@Input() date;`.

Also you can emit values to a parent via

```
@Output() emitter = new EventEmitter();

public emitValue(): void {
  this.emitter.emit(value);
}
```

And get emitted value in the parent component
`<app-picker (emitter)="handleEmit($event)></app-picker>`

parent-component.ts

```
public handleEmit(event) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Date-picker is not about Angular. Angular is just a way of implementation. But here you go https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview