# TS2702: 'JQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here

Tags: jquery, typescript, requirejs

Trying to use TS in a RequireJS client application.

In one file jquery library is accessed by:
`import $ = require("../libs/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js");` and in the same directory is the definition file:
`jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.d.ts` copied (and renamed) from the DefinitelyTyped site.

Now I have 293 errors, all from the definition file, mainly `TS2702: 'JQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

Tried to add as suggested somewhere: `declare module '../libs/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' {export = JQuery}` but every variation of it gives an error.

To be able to continue I resorted to the `<amd-dependency>` method.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript

Comment: Thanks, but I work client side, so no npm. Creating a `node_modules` repository will be the last ratio, if all else fails.

Comment: I found a very short `jquery.d.ts` somewhere, so I simply load jquery with RequireJS and <amd-dependency>, added this definition and `declare var $: JQueryStatic`. Even if not elegant seems to work.