# jQuery hasData does not exist in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I try to use the `hasData` method from jQuery in typescript like this:

```
$('.my-element').hasData("my-data")
```

But unfortunately it is not working. The error I got is

> (TS) Property 'hasData' does not exist on type 'jQuery'.

The Version is jquery-3.4.1.js.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You could cast it to  or extend the jquery typing to add your own method.

```
(<any>$('.my-element')).hasData("my-data");
```

//Or add your own custom methods

```
interface JQuery {
    hasData("my-data"):void;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both is working. I tried to append the method to the interface already, I was to impatient. The red error lines in the code needed some time to disappear.

Comment: I'm sorry. Does not work. Error in Browser `TypeError: $(...).hasData is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I believe for a full support you should use jQuery's TS declarations, instead of referring pure JS script. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052431/4108884

Comment: @types are implemented of course. Otherwise it won't work in anyway.