# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - importing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript

i have a problem with import statements in my website project. try to use nodejs - typescript and jquery

my project folder looks like that:

- Project

  - node_modules
  - public

    - js
    - jquery/dist (copy form node_modules/jquery/dist)
    - index.html
  - ts

    - test.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testclient",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "module": "ES2015",
        "moduleResolution": "Classic",
        "target": "ES5",
        "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2015", "es2015.promise"],
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "public/js",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": [
        "ts/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <header>
        <title>Test</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        Mein Test
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</html>
```

test.ts

```
import $  from 'jquery';
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('document is ready now');
    console.log($);
});
```

if i start the index.html in my chrome browser and open the console i get a error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    test.js:1

i figured out $ is not known at the moment i call it as jquery. so i cant use jquery in my script

what is the best practice to get it run without using `///<reference path=""/>` for importing jquery. which tsconfig params are to set to get it running in browser?

Comment: by the way, if i change test.ts:  `import $ from 'jquery` to `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"` all works. but thats not the way i search. import statements have to work i think

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question completely (it's a bit weird formulated) but I think you are trying to implement jquery in your index page without having to download and map it and you can simply do it by implementing this in your code:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Also you are getting the error because your path to test.js is wrong it should be

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../ts/test.js"></script>`

if I take your mapping in concideration

Comment: i have jquery local stored by node and dont want to load it from web. and the js file is found without problems

Comment: @mtizziani ok my bad, could it be in test.js that it should be: import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery'; If I remember correctly you have to use {}.

Comment: You could load it with require: `var jquery = require('jquery')`.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with jquery and typescript. Most likely you need to download and include the [TypeScript definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197665/188246) for jQuery—[`jquery.d.ts`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts)—in your project. Please make sure you fulfilled the following steps before trying to use jquery:

**Option 1: Install the @types package (Recommended for TS 2.0+)**

In your project run:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Then the compiler will resolve the definitions for jquery automatically.

**Option 2: Download Manually**

Download it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts).

**Option 3: Using Typings**

If you're using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) then you can include it this way:

```
// 1. Install typings
npm install typings -g
// 2. Download jquery.d.ts (run this command in the root dir of your project)
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

---

After setting up the definition file, import the alias (`$`) in the desired TypeScript file to use it as you normally would.

```
import $ from "jquery";
// or
import $ = require("jquery");
```

You mean need to compile with `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`—add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in *tsconfig.json*.

Comment: please have a look on the description, @types/jquery is defined in package.json and allready installed. and the tsconfig option is set to true, otherwise i get an error tsc is running

Comment: but do you have the TypeScript definition file for jQuery—jquery.d.ts?

Comment: yes, it is in node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts. if it is not installed tsc creates a compile error and my id also creates a error, but there is no error . and by the way, the typings module is outdated ;)