# Are there differences between declaring types for external modules in .ts or .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a project which needs to include:

1. Module declarations for JS libraries with no `@types` packages or bundled types.
2. Module augmentations for libraries which do have types, but they have bugs or in some cases recommend augmentation to customize (e.g. material-ui).

Currently we put them into `src/@types/library-name.d.ts` (or `src/@types/global.d.ts` for the global namespace. This works fine. But due to `skipLibCheck: true` any errors directly in these files don't get caught (and disabling it produces far too many errors in `node_modules`). So I thought of changing them all to `.ts` extension. If the files still look the same

```
declare module 'x' {
  // all declarations inside
}
```

is there any potential behavior difference between `.ts` and `.d.ts`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \*.d.ts vs \*.ts in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196657/what-is-the-difference-between-d-ts-vs-ts-in-typescript)

Comment: @kelsny No, because neither answer mentions the case I'm asking about: using a `*.ts` file only for declarations. I did find and read it before asking.