# The types export by declaration file can not be recognized when has the ts file with same name

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite

I'm new ts programmer, I have something confuse between the declaration file and the ts file, hope someone can explain me this, thank you. there are three files, utils.d.ts, utils.ts, run.ts, they are in same folder.

```
//utils.d.ts
export type name=string;
export type age=number;

export type fun=(p1:name,p2:age)=>name;



//utils.ts
import { fun } from "./utils.d"

export fun1:fun = (d1,d2)=>{
   console.log(d1,d2);
   return d1;
}



 //run.ts

 //situation 1: which is ok
 import { fun1 } from "./utils"

 //situation 2: which is ok
 import { name } from "./utils.d"

 //situation 3: prompt the 'name' is not export
 import { name } from "./utils"

 //situation 3: remove the utils.ts, which is ok
 import { name } from "./utils"
```

I'm very confuse about the relationship between .d.ts and .ts file, as my understand, when import from utils.ts, the complier will find all declaration of utils.ts and utils.d.ts, means I can do this

```
import { fun1, fun, name, age } from "./utils"
```

but in this sameple, I can only import fun1;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \*.d.ts vs \*.ts in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196657/what-is-the-difference-between-d-ts-vs-ts-in-typescript)